# GWSL and XDebug - Add tunnel to WSL for Xdebug in Shopware6 developer template

Tags: wsl-2, shopware6

I'm on Windows and use WSL.
I'm trying to run Phpstorm directly from WSL, involving GWSL. This to avoid file system sync between WSL and Windows.
Everything works perfectly except XDebug, listening to host.docker.internal is not working.
I'm using Shopware6 developer template, which creates a container for the webapp, with XDebug enabled.

I've seen a solution using socat to map a xdebug socket to the phpstorm listening port.
Can you help me doing it?

Answer (score 1):

When working with docker on wsl you have a network that contains a minimum of 3  hosts: `Windows -> WSL-Linux -> Docker-Linux`.
Hostname `host.docker.internal` pointed by default on Windows but you are running your IDE from WSL-Linux if you are using GWSL. So it is a different host and it couldn't be reached by hostname `host.docker.internal`.

I propose to do the next steps:

1. Get Ip address WSL-Linux. Run `hostname -I`
2. Check the connection between Docker-Linux and IDE.

   - Switch on port listening on your IDE
   - Go to the docker container. Run in WSL-Linux terminal `docker exec -it [your container name] sh`
   - There, run `telnet [wsl-linux ip from step1] 9000`.
     If you will see `Connected to [your ip]` then it is working and you could go to the next step.
3. Update setting `xdebug.remote_host` in `xdebug.ini` file your container

   - Go to the docker container. Run in WSL-Linux terminal `docker exec -it [your container name] sh`
   - Set `xdebug.remote_host=[wsl-linux ip from step1]` in your `xdebug.ini` (possible you will find it here  `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini`)
   - Restart your docker container `docker restart [your container name]`

Comment: telnet [wsl-linux ip from step1] 9000 is not connecting to WSL host.

Comment: To be sure that you testing exactly the connection with WSL-linux. You could run listening  9000 by netcat. Run in your WSL-Linux terminal `nc -l 9000`. Then check the connection by telnet as you described upper. 
 
If the connection has been established, check please if you switch on listening port 9000 on your IDE.

If you are using  [shopware-docker] (here https://github.com/shyim/shopware-docker) for checking clearly all of that, set WSL_XDEBUG_TUNNEL=false.

Comment: No way, netcat -l 9000 from WSL-Linux and telnet [WSL-Linux IP] 9000 from the container gives no output.
Indeed the WSL_XDEBUG_TUNNEL=true option creates a tunnel from the container to the WSL host. I'm not using shopware-docker indeed, but I'd like to create that tunnel as well